# My mongoose document saves correctly but isn't updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
   let addNoteToThisUser = await UserRecords.findOne({userid: message.author.id})
    addNoteToThisUser.content[1].note = `SWAMISHREEJI`
    addNoteToThisUser.save().then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

schema code:

```
const autoSchema = mongoose.Schema({

userid: String,
    content : [{type: Object}]
});
```

This code runs perfectly.
The `console.log(doc)` logs the document with the correct changes.
But when I see on Mongo atlas, it still is not updated. Also when I log the document again after freshly restarting the server, it still isn't changed while it clearly logged the fixed document in the `.save` promise. How to fix this?

Comment: Not an answer but `.save()` resolves itself rather than the document on the server. Maybe look at [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) settings. It should default to 1 but maybe it's been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, you have to mark the property as modified before saving.